# Множество словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, множества

Необходимо обрабатывать множество (`set()`) словарей, но, т.к. словарь не является хешируемым объектом, то и в множество его добавить не получится. Какое есть оптимальное решение для этого?

Сам смог додуматся только до json-сериализации словарей с ключом `sort_keys=True`, таким образом получится множество строк, в которое не получится добавить строку, которая при десериализации не совпадёт с любой десериализованной строкой из множества, но я не думаю, что это рациональное решение.

---

Прошу прощения, если вопрос задан непонятно, в комментариях постараюсь ответить на уточняющие вопросы.

Comment: Ну, первый вопрос - зачем вам множество словарей?

Comment: @insolor Есть 2 **списка** словарей, которые надо сравнить в том смысле, что все элементы из первого списка присутствуют во втором и нет лишних и наоборот, но порядок словарей в них может быть разным, из-за чего оператор `==` вернёт false negative, а операторов <, > для словарей нет, поэтому сравнивать отсортированные списки тоже не получится.

Comment: У функций сортировки есть параметр key, используя который можно отсортировать в принципе набор любых объектов. С другой стороны, если использовать set, то у вас могут потеряться дублирующиеся словари, если такие вдруг встретятся.

Comment: @insolor Дублирующихся точно нет. Также забыл добавить, что над множествами словарей потом будут проводиться другие операции, такие как: пересечение, объединение, вычитание. Поэтому очень важно, чтобы они хранились именно в контейнере `set()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сохранять словари в множество в виде объектов `tuple(sorted(d.items()))`. Если значения в словаре были хешируемы, то и полученный объект тоже будет хешируем. Сортировка нужна чтобы одинаковые словари гарантированно были преобразованы к одному виду. Обратное преобразование - просто `dict(x)`.